# How to access table_name variable in django?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

For example- My query changes for different tables at different instances. I have a string input which tells me which table I have to access at a particular instance, how do I query in django with such varying table?

Usually we query models.Person.objects.filter(), where table_name=Person(which remains same in every query). How do we query when table_name is a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get model by it's name using django apps.get_model method

```
>>> from django.apps import apps
>>> model_you_want = apps.get_model(app_label='app_name', model_name='model_name_string')
>>> model_you_want.objects.filter()
```

Answer (score 0):

with `eval` you can run a python statement which is in form of string.

I've tested the following on python 3 and django 1.8.x
exec keyword also works on python 2

```
table_name = 'Person'
query = "{0}.objects.all()".format(table_name)
result = eval(query)
```

Comment: Why would you use eval, if django has built-in utilities for retrospection?

Comment: Even though eval is slower and this approach requires your model to be imported to make that code work?

Comment: Can you suggest a faster approach? @Nick

Comment: @Serjick the above approach gives me a Name Error even though the table exists.

Comment: @MadhuryaGandi just try my approach in the answer below.